# Always the last element's informations are shown in the List (Java)

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have some Lists consist of some Apk files' informations:

```
static ContentAndDAO contentAndDao = new ContentAndDAO();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int manifestNum;
    long contentId = 111111;
    long devFileId = 222222;
    List<DevFile> fileList;
    List<DevSupport> supports = null;
    List<ContentDev> contentList = new ArrayList<ContentDev>(); 
    ContentDevDAO contentDevDao = new ContentDevDAO();
    DevFileDAO devFileDao = new DevFileDAO();       
    ManifestMethods manifestMethods = new ManifestMethods();
    DevFile apkFile = null;

    try 
    {   
        manifestNum = 1;

        File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\lenovo 01\\Desktop\\basari\\buulkcontent\\klasorlenen");
        String[] extensions = new String[] {"apk"};
        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);         
        Collections.sort(files);
        for(File file : files)
        {           
            apkFile = new DevFile();
            fileList = new ArrayList<DevFile>();

            if(file.getName().contains(".apk"))
            {                   
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                String apkMd5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis);
                fis.close();

                System.out.println(file);
                System.out.println(file.length());
                System.out.println(apkMd5.toUpperCase());
                System.out.println(contentId);

                apkFile.setByteSize(file.length()); 
                apkFile.setUrl("/file/getContent/" + contentDevDao.createId(contentId) + "/" + apkMd5.toUpperCase() + "/apk");                  
                apkFile.setThumbnailUrl("/file/getContent/" + contentDevDao.createId(contentId) + "/" + apkMd5.toUpperCase() + "/apk");
                apkFile.setDeleteUrl("/file/deleteContent/" + contentDevDao.createId(contentId) + "/" + apkMd5.toUpperCase() + "/apk");
                apkFile.setFileHash(apkMd5.toUpperCase());
                apkFile.setFilePath("content/" + contentDevDao.createId(contentId) + "/" + apkMd5.toUpperCase() + ".apk");                                                              
                apkFile.setFileName(manifestMethods.getApplicationName(manifestNum).replaceAll(" ", "-") + ".apk");
                apkFile.setName(manifestMethods.getApplicationName(manifestNum).replaceAll(" ", "-"));                      
                apkFile.setPackageVersion(manifestMethods.getVersionName(manifestNum));                     
                apkFile.setPackageName(manifestMethods.getPackageName(manifestNum));                    
                apkFile.setPackageVersionCode(manifestMethods.getVersionCode(manifestNum));                     
                apkFile.setSdkVersion(manifestMethods.getSdkVersion(manifestNum));

                contentId++;
                devFileId++;
                manifestNum++;     
            }           
        }

        for(int y = 1; y <= 53; y++)
        {               
            manifestNum = 1;
            fileList = new ArrayList<DevFile>();

            DevFile file = new DevFile();
            ContentDev content = new ContentDev();

            /* some DevFile file addings */

            fileList.add(file);                 
            content.setDevFiles(fileList);
            contentList.add(content);
        }                       
    }   
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I print the information one by one to the console, its showing just as I want. But in the List, its always showing only the last added apk file's package name, byte size, hash number etc. Of course I don't want that. What is wrong?

Note: Please don't mind the lack of legibility and modularity of code. I'm new to the object oriented structure.

Comment: "*Please don't mind the lack of legibility and modularity of code*" OK, but understand that those directly affect how both you and others are able to diagnose issues.  In fact, taking the time to modularize it often reveals the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new list in each iteration of your loop :

```
    for(int y = 1; y <= 53; y++)
    { 
        fileList = new ArrayList<DevFile>();
        DevFile file = new DevFile();
        ContentDev content = new ContentDev();

        /* some DevFile file addings */

        fileList.add(file);  
        ...
```

This means only the last file will be in that list at the end.

Change it to :

```
    fileList = new ArrayList<DevFile>();
    for(int y = 1; y <= 53; y++)
    { 
        DevFile file = new DevFile();
        ContentDev content = new ContentDev();

        /* some DevFile file addings */

        fileList.add(file);  
        ...
```

In addition, I see that you create instances of `DevFile` in another loop, but never do anything with them. Shouldn't they be added to the List?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't write them to not get clutter the code. This edit didn't change anything and now devFile is showing 10 elements. It should show only 1. I think my whole is flawed.